# jQuery - making .one run on any one element of a class, rather than once on every element?

Tags: jquery, class

I trying to get a popup to appear once, triggered when the user hovers over any one of a gallery of images (`class="notice"`). I tried `.one()`, which is helpful, but right now the message is appearing once for every image in the gallery. I would like it to appear only once for all the images, on whichever the user happens to hover over first.

Things I've tried:

- `*.first` and `.get(index)`, but those methods require you to specify only one image, I want any image to work
- `.removeClass('.notice')` on `mouseleave`, but jQuery is looking at the old DOM, so that doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.notice').one('mouseenter', function() {
        $('.popup').fadeIn(1000); 
        $(this).addClass('faded');
    })
    .one('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.popup').fadeOut(1000); 
        $(this).removeClass('faded'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you see this : `$('.notice').one()` instead of `$('.notice').on()` in your code?

Comment: @The-Val The question mentions the use of `one`  http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Ohh.. i was completly unaware of that, thanks pal. i learned one new thing :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just unbind it yourself:

```
var $notice = $('.notice');

$notice.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.popup').fadeIn(1000); 
    $(this).addClass('faded');

    $notice.off('mouseenter');
})
```

Comment: @elusive fair enough.  Updated.